# LTC7000 IC Iset pin broke in some way

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, high-side

I have a LTC7000 IC schematic like below. IC fault pin show around 10V and its fine. I can turn on and turn off mosfet at least 3 or 5 times. I can turn off mosfet under without current and after that Mosfet allow to pass current. But After that, IC fault pin show around 3V. And I can't turn on-off mosfet. When I measure IC's Iset pin, multimeter show 2.4K value with R5 and without R5. I measured R5 resistor speraitly from IC, its value fine. When I measure IC's pin with and without resistor, multimeter show 2.4K. IC broke in some way. How can I use this IC as it should be ?[image]

[LTC7000 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC7000-7000-1.pdf)

Comment: Do you use an inductive or pure resistive load? What is the Vcc voltage after the fault?

Comment: We are use resistive load. VCC Voltage oscillates around 2.6V and 4V.